# How can i get the feature name with GUID and Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature error

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, bi

we have a SharePoint 2013 test server and I created a Publishing site and BI site under this publishing site, when I try to deploy Performance point dashboards to SharePoint site I found below errors in uls logs

I created a custom master page in the publishing site.

> Failed to determine the setup path of the list schema for feature
>   {34FF858A-9C87-44D3-9E85-xxxxx}, list template 12593.
>
> Exception in GetFeatureRootAndListSchemaPaths:
>   System.ArgumentException: at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c__DisplayClass19.b__18()

How can i get the feature name with GUID

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint 2013 Management Shell (as Administrator) and this command:

```
Get-SPfeature | ? {$_.Id -eq "ec6b663d-92a1-4cd3-9fed-xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Comment: Hi after above command run no results came ,how can I get or remove that custom list template I'd 12593

Comment: try "Get-SPsite" and after this "Site.Features" if there will be shown, otherwise you can use Uninstall-SPfeature cmd.